# How do I list Security Groups of current Instance in AWS EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**EDIT** Removed BOTO from question title as it's not needed.
Is there a way to find the security groups of an EC2 instance using Python and possible Boto?

I can only find docs about creating or removing security groups, but I want to trace which security groups have been added to my current EC2 instance.

Comment: boto or boto3??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the security groups of current instance, you don't need Boto/Boto3. Make use of the AWS meta-data server.

```
import os
sgs = os.popen("curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups").read()
print sgs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it from that instance and execute below command

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups`

or from aws-cli also

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups`

Comment: Neither of this worked here, aws --region ... ec2 seems to list all security groups, and the ip of curl is wrong, the one provided by @helloV works

Comment: My bad..I was just posting from.mobile so forgot to check the right ip

Comment: NP appreciate your help